# NullReference on a value that is not null

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have a function that gets a string passed to it.  When testing the function, I'm getting a null reference exception on the string parameter that gets passed to it, even though the string is not null, I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  I have a screen shot below

[image]

I used a dummy value to verify both the string parameter in the SelectSingleNode function and the newValue string parameter being passed to my function and they both contain values, so I don't understand why it's throwing a null reference exception.  Just for clarity, the purpose of the function is to write values back to the nodes of an XML file.

UPDATE

Sorry for not posting code

```
Private Sub setValue(ByVal nodeToMod As String, ByVal newValue As String)
        ''Test writing to xml config file
        Dim dummy As String = "Config/" & nodeToMod
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML_Config/Config.xml"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
            xmlDoc.Load(fs)
            Dim foo As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(dummy)
            Console.WriteLine(foo.InnerXml)
            fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            fs.SetLength(0)
            xmlDoc.Save(fs)
        End Using
    End Sub
```

And here is the XML file I'm working with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Username>john.doe@email.com</Username>
  <Password>Password1</Password>
  <ProductType>MyProduct</ProductType>
  <DirectoryEntryPath>LDAP://myDomain</DirectoryEntryPath>
  <SMTPDefaultOnly>True</SMTPDefaultOnly>
  <Logo>myLogo.gif</Logo>
</Config>
```

Yes, the SlectSingleNode function is not returning a value.  I just started working with XPath, this seemed to have worked when I was using last week.  I'm not sure why it has stopped working now.

UPDATE2:

Got it, stupid mistake. I had nodeToMod being passed as "UserName" instead of "Username" in the Set method

```
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            setValue("UserName", value.ToString)
            _userName = value
        End Set
```

Comment: You might want to show us more of the code. If it gives null exception then the "newValue" is definitely null at the time of its assigning to innertext.

Comment: @loxxy, `newValue` is not being dereferenced on that line.  It cannot be the reason for the NRE.

Comment: @kirk, the question has been edited with more info. The dereference  was not obvious earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The null reference that is being complained about is the *result* of the call to `SelectSingleNode`. That is, when the xpath formed by concatenating `/Config/` and the contents of `nodeToMod` is evaluated against the document, no node matches. So you get null, and attempting to set the `InnerText` of null gives the exception.

We would really need to see `nodeToMod` and the xml file itself to help further. Also, please post code rather than screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the FileStream object you're creating doesn't come out null. Maybe it can't find the config.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the result of `SelectSingleNode` is null.

Change that line to two lines, and it will be easier to see the problem in the debugger:

```
Dim node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(dummy)
node.InnerText = newValue
```